# CSS - center and rounded Img Inside Div

Tags: html, css, image, center

I have an Img inside a Div on my webpage, the image appears inside the div, but the alignment is off depending on the browser width.

this is my code:

```
<div class="w3-row" style="100%; background-color: #fff; margin-top: 5px; height: 100px; padding: 5px;">
    <div class="w3-col w3-container w3-green" style="width: 15%; height: 100%;">
        <div>
            <img class="" src="../images/Joanne.jpg" alt="Chania" style="height: 80px; display: block;  margin-left: auto;  margin-right: auto;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-col w3-container w3-red" style="width: 85%; height: 100%;">

    </div>
</div>
```

I was wondering if there was a way I could vertically and horizontally align the Image inside that Div, and maybe also have the image with rounded corners.

I have searched around but nothing I try works, I thought by setting the margin left and right to 'auto' would solve my problem, but the image is still off when I resize the browser.

Any help or advice is appreciated.

**Demo:**https://jsfiddle.net/jjxbm7j7/

Comment: add jsdiddle for this, because rounded corners you could add using border-radius.

Comment: Be careful with posting personal photos on here. This is still the Internet, and still a public forum. Evil lurks everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a rounded image - use the border-radius property

For a vertically centered image - Use display:flex and align-items:center on the parent element of the image that has a specified height.

For a horizontally centered image - display:flex and justify-content:center on the parent element of the image that has a specified width.
However, for your example, I used margin:auto, because it is actually simpler.

For more information for flex stuff, click here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

It should look like this:

```css
.image {
  border-radius: 50px;
}
.w3-col.w3-container.w3-green {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
}
.w3-row {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-row" style="100%; background-color: #fff; margin-top: 5px; height: 100px; padding: 5px;">
  <div class="w3-col w3-container w3-green" style="width: 15%; height: 100%;">
    <div>
      <img class="image" src="http://s33.postimg.org/vnc0xbztb/Joanne.jpg

" alt="Chania" style="height: 80px; display: block;  margin-left: auto;  margin-right: auto;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--<div class="w3-col w3-container w3-red" style="width: 85%; height: 100%;">

  </div>-->
</div>
```

I added the 1px border property for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

### Perfectly Center your Image inside a DIV using **transform: scale()**

I have created a box inside that i have placed your image to show how to center the image inside the **div(class="box")** .

```
body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.w3-row {
  display: flex; //flexBox
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column; //Works as a Stack i.e Image at the Top and Description at the bottom
}
```

For Scaling Image using CSS Transformations

```
.image{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transform: scale(.5); //change the scale value to change size of the Image 0<scale<1
}
```

For Rounded Image

```
.img-rounded{
  border-radius: 50%
}
```

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rittamdebnath/jjxbm7j7/3/

Answer (score 0):

before anything it's not good approach to write inline CSS but anyway you can use vertical align way on an sudo element (after) like so

```css
.image {
    border-radius: 50px; //adjust yourself
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
  
}

.w3-col.w3-container.w3-green{
   
    text-align:center;
    height:100px;
   border:1px solid;
   width:100%;
}
.w3-col.w3-container.w3-green:after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-row" style="100%; background-color: #fff; margin-top: 5px; height: 100px; padding: 5px;">
    <div class="w3-col w3-container w3-green" style="width: 15%; margin:auto;">

            <img class="image" src=" http://s33.postimg.org/vnc0xbztb/Joanne.jpg" alt="Chania" style="height: 80px;  ">

    </div>
    <div class="w3-col w3-container w3-red" style="width: 85%; height: 100%;">

    </div>
</div>
```